How to properly customize an File Input in react.js
I have a problem when customizing <input type='file'/> element.
Since I'm new to react.js and JS I didn't know how to change the default 'Choose File' text of the input element so I've found a short tutorial ('https://3body-net.medium.com/how-to-style-a-file-input-in-react-b6a141418341') and it worked but I still have an small error (I think) and a few questions.
This is the component for the file input customization.
import React, {useState, useRef} from "react";

const ImageInput = ({ file, setFile }) => {
  const fileInput = useRef(null);

  const onChange = async (event) => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      setFile(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <input 
        type="file"
        name="image"
        ref={fileInput}
        onChange={onChange}
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
      />
      <button
        className="upload-btn"
        onClick={() => fileInput.current.click()}
        style={{ width: '40%', fontSize: '14px', marginBottom: '10px' }}
      >Upload Image</button>
    </>
  );
}
export default ImageInput;

and this is my parent component(used for creating player entity)
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "../../assets/styles/form/adminCreatePlayerForm.css";
import ImageInput from "./ImageInput";

const CreatePlayer = () => {
  const [playerData, setPlayerData] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    photoUrl: '',
  });
  // probat izbacit playerImg, koristit samo photoUrl...u handleFileChange napravit isto sta i u handleSubmit s updatedPlayerData
  const [playerImg, setPlayerImg] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setPlayerData({
      ...playerData,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };
  // *** I don't need 'handleFileChange' anymore since I've created ImageInput component
  // const handleFileChange = (event) => {
  //   setPlayerImg(event.target.files[0]);
  // };

  // *** event.preventDefault(); - stops page from reloading on submit, also if validation is done on FE
  // it stops form submission and checks the validation rules
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('playerImg', playerImg);
    
    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/files/upload", formData).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      const photoName = response.data.imageName;
      const updatedPlayerData = ({
        ...playerData,
        photoUrl: photoName,
      });
      axios.post("http://localhost:8080/players", updatedPlayerData).then((response) => { 
        console.log(response);
      });
    });

    // reseting form after submit
    setPlayerData({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      photoUrl: '',
    })
    setPlayerImg(null);
  };

  return (
    <div className="create-player-container">
      <h1>Add New Player</h1>
      <div className="create-player-form">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="create-player-form-field">
            <label htmlFor="firstName">
              First Name
            </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="firstName"
                value={playerData.firstName}
                onChange={handleChange}
               />
            </div>

          <div className="create-player-form-field">
            <label htmlFor="lastName">
              Last Name
              <input
                type="text"
                name="lastName"
                value={playerData.lastName}
                onChange={handleChange}
               />
            </label>
          </div>

          <div className="create-player-form-field">
            <label htmlFor="profile-picture">
            </label>
              <ImageInput file={playerImg} setFile={setPlayerImg}/>
                    </div>
          <button type="submit">Create</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default CreatePlayer;


My first ambiguity is why does the ImageInput recieve 2 arguments(2 props in world of react ?) when the first one file is never used?
Second why is async used here const onChange = async (event) => { , does it make sense to declare it asynchronous and then not use await keyword, what is the benefit of it?

And finally the error -> when I click the 'Upload Image' button (before actually choosing one) instantly I can see an Axios Error in console saying detail: "Required part 'playerImg' is not present."
(On the screenshot I've uploaded more detailed axios response can be seen.)
Edit: stack owerflow doesn't let me post images yet
Since I don't have a deeper understanding I don't understand why does it detect there is no image present before I even select one.


file and setFile are just states to save the file. if file is not getting used in  then you can remove it from here
<ImageInput setFile={setPlayerImg}/>.

you can safely remove async for onChange function.

In your ImageInput component add type="button" .
Your form is submitted right after clicking this button because it's assuming this button as a submit button.


<button type="button">
